# knowing the orders that done through a specific link in my online store

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

I have an online store and I do a lot of campaigns
But I'm having a hard time figuring out how do I know this customer came from which campaign?

Google Analytics gives me general information about the campaign like, conversion rate, page views, revenue...etc

But what I'm looking for if there is any way to find out the reference order numbers, customer names, and phone numbers that came through the given link

I found a solution but later found out that it doesn't work which is:

Add an iframe in the external domain and design it to cover the whole page and contain my website, so users won't even notice they're on a site within a site

Then if the user reaches the checkout page, I extract his information and send it to the database

But then I found it difficult to track users through an iframe

Is there any way to solve my problem in an easy way like tag manager or if there are any tools available that can help me achieve my goal

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this mean the actual checkout page is not under your control and does not send any data back to you? Also storing personal information in Google Analytics is against Google's terms of service (and in some countries actually against the law, although that depends on your jurisdiction).